How do I get checkbox status from scanned document using Azure AI Document Intelligence?
I have a multi page scanned form about vehicle health check status. It has many tables and checkmarks (ticked, unchecked). I can read the selection status using Azure AI document status, using selection under page.
motorXXX_doc.pages[62].selection_marks

However, I could not get the label for each checkbox. Any help? Thank you.
